# How to serialize Dictionary with ODataMediaTypeFormatter in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I want serialaze Dictionary im model with ODataMediaTypeFormatter.

JsonNet serialize Dictionary as object:

```
{ 
Length: 10,
Weight: 100,
}
```

ODataMediaTypeFormatter (with ODataJsonLight serializer) serialize as empty array:

```
[
{},
{}
]
```

ODataMediaTypeFormatter serialize Dictionary as Collection of KeyValuePair and KeyValuePair as empty object.

I try override default formatter and convert Dictionary to ComplexType with parameters, but i had Edm Validation Error in ODataJsonLight serializer (it's a part of Microsoft.Data.Edm).

Does anyone have any ideas how to serialize dictionaries normal?

Comment: It's going to be impossible to get OData to understand what your value of `object` is unless you use interfaces or abstract classes. e.g. `KeyValuePair<string, MyBaseType>`

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are not standard data types in OData. So, web API OData does not support them native. You can however model them as collection of keyvalue pair(complex type), though I would suggest you to have a special type declared for that.

Anyways, the code for modelling would be (assuming you have`Dictionary<string,string>`),

```
Type kvpType = typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
var kvpEdmType = builder.AddComplexType(kvpType);
kvpEdmType.AddProperty(kvpType.GetProperty("Key"));
kvpEdmType.AddProperty(kvpType.GetProperty("Value"));
```

Comment: This approach works with `KeyValuePair<string, string>` but doesn`t works with `KeyValuePair<string, object>`.

Comment: Works perfectly for KeyValuePair<string, string> I'm guessing its because OData Convention Model Builder doesn't work with immutable types.